# How To render Mustache Partial in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, mustache.php

I'm using this module https://github.com/widmogrod/zf2-mustache-module

module.config

```
'strategies' => array(
    'Mustache\View\Strategy'
),

'template_map' => array(
    'My_Main' => __DIR__ . '/../view/main.phtml',
    'My_SideBar'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/partials/templates.mustache',
),

'mustache' => array(
    'partials_loader' => array(__DIR__ . '/../view/partials'),
),
```

templates.mustache

```
<div>
<p>Book Title: {{ title }}</p>
</div>
```

main.phtml view

```
<?php 
echo $this->partial('My_SideBar', array('title' => 'My partial'));
?>
```

Output: 
Book Title : {{ title }}